# Analyzing satisfaction levels of PhD scholars

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, multiple-regression, reliability

I am analyzing satisfaction levels of PhD scholars in a particular region.

We got 7 independent variables from literature review and constructed 45 questionnaires accordingly: for example, 5 questions related to stress, 4 questions on scholar-guide relation etc. Likert 5 point scales are used.

I have done reliability tests of all the 45 items (combining all the items of 7 independent variables). We found Cronbach alpha 0.750 which is reliable but when I try to do reliability test for questions related only to stress it is showing 0.44, similar to another independent variable showing below 0.7. Is  reliability test necessary here as I have picked all the independent variables from literature review but constructed my questionnaire related it as it was not found in the LR.

I have done stepwise regression on the mean of 7 independent variables and found this. [image]

KMO test shows 0.560.

Is my analysis going in the right direction?

Comment: Please check that my edits did not change your meaning. I wasn't clear when _questionnaires_ meant questionnaires (number of people) and when it meant questions. How many people did you study?

Comment: hi Nick thanks for your response ..........we study only one institute total population is 425 Phd students , we consider only full time Phd student which is 315 and our sample size is 175. The questionnaires means the questions we constructed related to 7 independent variable. as i have mention like for stress (there are 5 question related to stress out of total 45 questions )

Comment: How is satisfaction measured? A small point, but one already made through edits: the usual rendering is PhD or Ph.D. not Phd.

Comment: Ya we ask if they are overall satisfied with the Phd program, and ask them to rate from strong agree to strongly disagree , 5 point Likert scale and we are using it as dependent variable.

Comment: To me that implies ordered logistic or ordered probit, not plain regression.

Comment: thanks for suggestion Nick , is it ok if my data is not normality distributed to run logistic regression and can you please share some view on reliability test do i need this , I doing research for first time

Comment: Whether you have a normal distribution of anything is irrelevant to ordered regressions. Frankly, I don't think you can do a good job here without spending several hours reading texts on categorical data analysis to understand that. You can't do good research without a basic understanding of the techniques you're using.

Comment: hi Nick i will read this techniques properly and try to run it , Thanks for feedback regards